# How to get Nvidia drivers to properly work in Ubuntu 18.04 running on ESXI 6.5?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I am trying to install Nvidia drivers on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 running on an ESXI 6.5 host. I have a Quadro K2200 configured as PCI Pass-Trough.

So far i have done the following:

1. Added "hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"" to the VM config.
2. Added the following file:
   `cat /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf

   blacklist nouveau
   blacklist lbm-nouveau
   alias nouveau off
   alias lbm-nouveau off`
3. Run the following commands to apply and install everything:
    `sudo update update-initramfs -u
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
    sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade 
    sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418`

Ok, so far so good, driver shows up as installed and *nvidia-smi* works:
`NVIDIA-SMI 418.43       Driver Version: 418.43       CUDA Version: 10.1`
lspci:
`lspci -k | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
        Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
        Kernel driver in use: vmwgfx
        Kernel modules: vmwgfx
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K2200] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K2200]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia`

The problem is, that there is a second VGA/VMware graphics adapter. It is set as the main display and OpenGL won't change to the nvidia card.
`glmark2
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     VMware, Inc.
    GL_RENDERER:   SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM; <<<<---- should be the card
    GL_VERSION:    3.1 Mesa 18.2.8`
 
I tried everything I know and out of ideas now... maybe someone knows how to get this card to work and run OpenGL.
Some Notes: currently no X-Config, nvidia-settings does not work (blank window) but nvidia is set as prime. (probably because of VMware VGA Adapter)

```
nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:9748): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 22:52:30.006: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 22:52:30.016: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 22:52:30.016: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

So is it better to try and just get OpenGL working with the card? Or switch the main Display to the card? Does VMware-Tools cause problems?

Thanks in advance!